# NodeJS Rest Services passing parameter to $near query MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

i have develop a list of Rest Services with NodeJS and MongoDB. One of these service execute a $near mongodb query to retrive all element into a specific range by a specific position

```
 router.route("/api/geo_cars")
.get(function(req,res){
    var max = 1000;
    var response = {};
    mongoOOp.find({
 location:
   { $near :
      {
        $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ 12.560945, 41.957482 ] },
        $maxDistance: max
      }
   }
},function(err,data){
    // Mongo command to fetch all data from collection.
        if(err) {
            response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error fetching data"};
        } else {
            response = {"error" : false,"message" : data};
        }
        res.json(response);
    });
});
```

The service is a get service and works very well.
Now i woutld like to pass to $near query the maxDistance value and coordinates by Service and i have try in this way for only maxDistance:

```
router.route("/api/geo_cars/:maxDistance")
.get(function(req,res){
    var max = req.params.maxDistance;
    var response = {};
    mongoOOp.find({
 location:
   { $near :
      {
        $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ 12.560945, 41.957482 ] },
        $maxDistance: max
      }
   }
},function(err,data){
    // Mongo command to fetch all data from collection.
        if(err) {
            response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error fetching data"};
        } else {
            response = {"error" : false,"message" : data};
        }
        res.json(response);
    });
});
```

but when i run the service in postman the response is a error "Error fetching data".
Any help how i can pass this value to $near query by service as parameter?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express treats all values passing in as strings.  Converting maxDistance to integer should work.

```
var max = parseInt(req.params.maxDistance);
```